# Python: AttributeError: 'PngImageFile' object has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, ocr, imread

I want to test my OCR code with an image named "S.png" which is located in the same folder as the python file.

I tried this code:

```
import numpy as np
import os
import string
import sys
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw
from skimage.io import imread
from sklearn.model_selection import ShuffleSplit
from TFANN import ANNC

def ImageToString(I):
    '''
    Uses OCR to transform an image into a string
    '''
    SI = DivideIntoSubimages(I)
    YH = cnnc.predict(SI)
    ss = SubimageShape(I)
    return JoinStrings(YH, ss)

#OCR code...

for img in sys.argv[1:]:
    print(sys.argv[1:]) #I get: [] I don't know why it doesn't show S.png 
    I = imread(img)
    S = ImageToString(I)
    print("S= "+str(S))
```

It doesn't generate an error, nor any result. Then I tried this code:

```
img = Image.open("S.png")
print("img= "+str(img)) #=> img= <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image 
                            mode=RGB size=969x1261 at 0x1D9994C0F28>
I = imread(img, 'RGB') #this line generates the error desvribed below
S = ImageToString(I)
print("S= "+str(S))
```

This is the printed error:

```
File "C:/Users/Hounaîda/Documents/pfe/ANN_OCR/DeepOCR.py", line 203, in <module>
    I = imread(img)

  File "C:\Users\Hounaîda\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\io\_io.py", line 61, in imread
    img = call_plugin('imread', fname, plugin=plugin, **plugin_args)

  File "C:\Users\Hounaîda\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\io\manage_plugins.py", line 211, in call_plugin
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Hounaîda\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\io\_plugins\pil_plugin.py", line 43, in imread
    im = Image.open(fname)

  File "C:\Users\Hounaîda\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2486, in open
    prefix = fp.read(16)

AttributeError: 'PngImageFile' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Comment: Can someone help me please !!

Comment: Please post `all` your code.

Comment: thanks for answering, I update the post

Comment: @Dwhitz I posted all the code, can you help me, please !!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I solved the problem by using the following code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

   I = imread("S.png") 
   S = ImageToString(I)
   print("S= "+str(S))
```